# Rails pluralize count when zero, does not work with number_with_delimiter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pluralize

I am trying to make a pluralization work with zero case and also using `number_with_delimiter` to make it readable with bigger numbers.

So, I have in my YAML file:

```
count:
  zero: no counts
  one: 1 count
  other %{count} counts
```

And in the view:

```
t 'count', number_with_delimiter(count)
```

The problem is, it does not work with the zero case. It handle it as other case. But, if I leave out the `number_with_delimiter` method it work as expected.

It is possible to pluralize with a number format handling also the zero case?

Comment: It seems that :count thing works with numbers but number_with_delimeter is a string technically, so I see no way other than implementing your custom helper/whathever method

Comment: why use number_with_delimiter as a second parameter when you need to provide a number? number_with_delimiter is a helper that transforms a number to a string ¿?

Comment: So I should choose between formatting the number or pluralize the string?

Answer (score 1):

Rails already have helpers to pluralize the string according to the count given.

```
2.1.5 :037 > helper.pluralize(0,'count')
 => "0 counts" 
2.1.5 :038 > helper.pluralize(1,'count')
 => "1 count" 
2.1.5 :039 > helper.pluralize(2,'count')
 => "2 counts"
```

Comment: This does not use any i18n method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to I18n pluralize a number with format handling.

That being said, the `count` has to be a Number in order to work so we can't use it.
The trick is to pass an **extra variale** to your translation.

Let's say we have a `points` variable.

```
t 'total_points', count: points, formatted_points: number_with_delimiter(points)
```

And in your YAML file:

```yaml
total_points:
  zero: '0 points'
  one: '1 point'
  other: '%{formatted_points} points'
```

`count` variable will be used to determine which translation to pick and `formatted_points` will be used for interpolation.

Here is another alternative: https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/issues/328#issuecomment-260217071